# Sharing to Facebook Stories

Tags: facebook, facebook-android-sdk

We were able to implement sharing to Instagram Stories, but not to Facebook Stories, following [these](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/sharing-to-stories) instructions . Android is not able to find an app for the intent `com.facebook.stories.ADD_TO_STORY`, despite Facebook app being installed and updated. Has anybody been able to accomplish that?

Answer (score 4):

It might be too late but i thought to answer it if it can help people who might be facing issues in sharing to instagram without Intent Chooser dialog.

---

Facebook expects us to launch an intent chooser dialog to select from 4 -5 activities within facebook app itself that can handle com.facebook.stories.ADD_TO_STORY as action.

---

Nevertheless here is the code i used to launch the exact story editor screen from facebook app. It uses ACTION_SEND instead of com.facebook.stories.ADD_TO_STORY.
So First define a fileprovider inside application tag in manifest

```
<provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_provider_paths" />
        </provider>
```

Then keep file_provider_paths.xml inside xml folder in res directory.
file_provider_paths.xml

```
<paths>
    <external-path
        name="share"
        path="/" />
</paths>
```

Then perpare a uri of file you want to share

```
File file = new File(imagePath);
Uri fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(),getPackageName()+".fileprovider",file);
```

Then send intent to facebook as below

```
Intent storiesIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
storiesIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.facebook.katana", "com.facebook.composer.shareintent.AddToStoryAlias"));
storiesIntent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");//for background image
storiesIntent.putExtra("interactive_asset_uri", uri);//for sticker assets
storiesIntent.putExtra("content_url", "https://dexati.com/");
grantUriPermission("com.facebook.katana", uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivityForResult(storiesIntent, 0);
```

Here we are making explicit call to the story editor activity of facebook app.

Comment: The above code works for Instagram! But how to share to Facebook story?

Comment: @TheOska apologies for late reply , I have updated answer to work for facebook stories. Please check

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it seems that it shares to Facebook feed instead of stories

Comment: Any solution for this?