# How to implement a button share to Instagram and WhatsApp Stories

Tags: android, ios, mobile, instagram, whatsapp

We need to implement a Share Button in our app that allows users to share images to WhatsApp Statuses or Instagram Stories.

Spotify currently has a button that allows you to share a Story to Instagram. However I haven’t been able to find any documentation on how to implement this for Instagram or WhatsApp.

Can this functionality be implemented in iOS and Android? If so how?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look to the official documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/sharing-to-stories/

Despite the instruction, my app still crash because it can't find the proper activity like explained in this question: [Sharing to Facebook Stories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50355564/sharing-to-facebook-stories)

I'll let you now i will make some progress